# Refactoring bootstrap nested tags in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, refactoring, dry

What's the best way to refactor the following snippet?:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        blah blah balh
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        blah blah balh
    </div>
</div>
```

For example a razor global helper function or something like that.
Considering the header and body content as **HTML** parameters.

Comment: This could be resolved by a custom HtmlHelper or a DisplayTemplate... What's the problem you're facing ?

Comment: Htmlhelper is not good enough because of intermingle of HTML and C# codes. How DisplayTemplate could help me? There isn't any specified model. The problem is removing duplication and simplifying view code.

Comment: There is another problem with HtmlHelper approach, the passed parameters could be HTML but in string form which make them hard to use. Considering passing a large amount of html for the body of the panel as string!

Comment: See these posts for other approaches to factoring razor code: stackoverflow.com/a/67656536/268581 stackoverflow.com/a/67657283/268581